# Inserting data to table from another table with a form

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Heyo,

This is the table named `api`

```
+----+----------+--------+-------+
| id |   name   | symbol | price |
+----+----------+--------+-------+
|  1 | bitcoin  | btc    |    10 |
|  2 | ethereum | eth    |     5 |
+----+----------+--------+-------+
```

And these are the columns for the table `testing`

```
+----+--------+-------+-------+
| id | symbol | coins | price |
+----+--------+-------+-------+
```

What I want to accomplish is for `symbol` and `price` which has values in `api` to be inserted into the `testing` table in its respective rows when I fill out this form:

```
<form method="post">
   <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
      <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Choose coin</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
         <select class="form-control" name="coin">
            <?php
            $stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT id, name, symbol FROM api');
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
               echo '<option id="'.$row['id'].'" value="'.$row['symbol'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
            }
            ?>
         </select>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
      <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">How many coins do you have?</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
         <input type="number" class="form-control" name="coins" placeholder="1">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group row justify-content-center text-center">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

But my main problem here is that I also want to insert something that's not inside of the `api` table. I have `<input type="number" class="form-control" name="coins" placeholder="1">` where I can type in a number and that number will be inserted in `coins` row.

I think the **select**

```
<select class="form-control" name="coin">
   <?php
   $stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT id, name, symbol FROM api');
   while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
      echo '<option id="'.$row['id'].'" value="'.$row['symbol'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
   }
   ?>
</select>
```

Has a factor here, by using the select field I want to fetch the data from the selected `echo '<option id="'.$row['id'].'" value="'.$row['symbol'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';` but I dont know how to go forward with this.

I think I've done something right with this code:

```
<?php

   $host = '127.0.0.1';
   $db = 'db_learning';
   $user = 'root';
   $pass = '';
   $charset = 'utf8mb4';

   $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
   $opt = [
   PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
   PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
   PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
   ];
   $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);

   if(!empty($_POST)) {

      if(empty($_POST['coins'])) {
         #die
         die("Please enter how many coins you have.");
      }

      $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO testing (coin, coins) VALUES (:coin, :coins)");

      $stmt->bindParam(':coin', $coin);
      $stmt->bindParam(':coins', $coins);

      # insert the row
      $coin = $_POST['coin'];
      $coins = $_POST['coins'];
      $stmt->execute();
   }
?>
```

But it does only give me values in `coin` and `coins` on submission of the form above which is not a shock due to what I've told it to do.

Can someone guide me here?

Thanks, and happy holidays from a newborn php newbie.

Comment: You're binding the params before you set the value. Swap those around and you should be good

Comment: @WillParky93 I swapped them around but it still didn't get any data from the other table named `api`. Although it did insert the `coin` and `coins` values into `testing` table, when I submitted the form, but so it already did before I swapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the supplied schematic of the table `testing` it doesn't have a column `coin` so the statement is probably failing to be prepared.
At the very least you should test if the statement object is created before proceeding - like this:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO testing (coin, coins) VALUES (:coin, :coins)");
if( $stmt ){
    $stmt->bindParam(':coin', $coin);
    $stmt->bindParam(':coins', $coins);
}
```

But it looks more likely that the column to receive the value should be `symbol`

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO testing (symbol, coins) VALUES (:symbol, :coins)");
if( $stmt ){
    $stmt->bindParam(':symbol', $coin);
    $stmt->bindParam(':coins', $coins);
}
```

or to insert the price as well ~ using a `try/catch` to detect and respond to failed sql prepare call...

```
try{
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("insert into testing (`symbol`, `coins`, `price` ) values ( :symbol, :coins, ( select `price` from `api` where `symbol`=:apisymbol ) )");
    if( $stmt ){
        $stmt->bindParam(':symbol', $coin );
        $stmt->bindParam(':coins', $coins );
        $stmt->bindParam(':apisymbol',$coin );
    } else {
        throw new Exception( "Statement failed" );
    }
}catch( Exception $e ){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```